# Difficulty getting UITableView to call `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:` appropriately

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

My table view implements footers on each section, of which there are many. I have the methods `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:` and `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` implemented, both now with `NSLogs` to confirm their getting printed. They do, but with a longer table view, the checking of `heightForFooterInSection:` for every section causes a delay.

I had this same issue with cells - I solved it by implementing `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` when cells are implemented, and now it only checks their actual height when the cell makes its' way into view.

But implementing `tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 32` actually causes every section footer to be of height `0`, and `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:` and `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` aren't called.

How can I get my table view to call `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:`, only when it's required, not for every section in a table view?

Comment: What are you doing in your implementation of `tableView:heightForFooterInSection`? Are you performing complex computations?

Comment: @a.periz Each section shows data with a particular timestamp. The header height is different if a longer time period has passed, rather than a short one, in regards to the previous section.

Comment: I have resolved a similar issue in the distant past by replacing the footer by an actual `UITableViewCell`. It appears that this feature is uncommon enough to have lingering iOS bugs.